# WSO2 Api Manger 3.0.0 how to use HA routing of services

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have two API servers running in HA mode i.e. same set of services are running on both VMs with same environment. We would like to use WSO2 APIM for API Security but the problem is that we have not been able to find how to use HA routing services in WSO2 APIM.
E.g.

1. API Server 1- http://192.168.0.2/getCustomerDetails
2. API Server 2- http://192.168.0.3/getCustomerDetails

API Gateway- 192.168.0.10

Once registered on API Gateway the service endpoints become-

1. URL1- https://192.168.0.10:8243/getCustInfo1

[edit]

2. URL2- https://192.168.0.10:8243/getCustInfo2

Now the question is how does WSO2 APIM decides where to route the request i.e. URL1 or URL2 for accessing the same business service? Or there is some concept like virtual ip usage in WSO2 APIM?

Comment: @TMKasun can you please giver your expert comment?

Comment: What's the difference between URL1 and URL2? how did you get those 2?

Comment: URL1 refers to registering the API of API server1 on API Gateway (192.168.0.10) and URL2 refers to registering the API of API server2. You may consider API Server 1 & 2 are in high availability mode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create 2 APIs in API Manager for your 2 backend URLs. Create a single API and use Load Balancing or Failover Endpoints[1].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/DesignAPI/Endpoints/high-availability-for-endpoints/

Comment: Thanks. Will try to implement the same.

Comment: is it possible to have active-active mechanism in failover option because currently it is active-passive mode in wso2 api 3.0.0.

Comment: Failover means active-passive. Loadbalancing means active-active. Both are supported.

Comment: Thanks Bee, I have tested out both options but both are available in isolate manner. I have a requirement of both options concurrently i.e. services should be discovered via LB and if any LB endpoint is down, then instead of throwing error request should be served from next available node. Currently if I choose LoadBalancer option then if any node is down then it throws error of network failure (round robin ).